# Python Pytorch model to C++ model

Tags: python, c, pytorch, compilation, onnx

I am looking for a way to export my Python pytorch model to a C++ model. At the end of the export I would like to have a file with executable C code for the model, not a binary executable or .exe-file.

The C++ model should work on a microcontroller.

I tried several ways to export the model:

- Pytorch-Model → Onnx-Model → onnx2c
- Pytorch-Model → Matlab-Model → matlabModel2c
- Pytorch-Model → Onnx-Model → Tensorflow-Model

None of these paths work for me and my model.
I have a large Temporal Convolutional Model with a few operations that does not work with onnx2c or Matlab2c.

Is there any other or easier way to create C code?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you are talking about C or C++? They are two different languages.

Comment: Did you consider TorchScript? https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html Please [edit] your question and add more details. In which way does it not work? Show the error message or actual result vs. expected result.